# Python program to extract next entry from a json

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
{"release": [{date: "03/03/2018 ",version:"10.0.1 ", installed_date=""},{date: "03/05/2018 ",version:"10.0.2 ", installed_date=""},{date: "03/04/2018 ",version:"10.0.3 ", installed_date=""}]}
```

From the above json file, 
need a program that acccepts the version, and matches the json file for the given version and gets the next version from the json.

examples

```
sample.py 10.0.1
output: 10.0.2

sample.py 10.0.2
output: 10.0.3

sample.py 10.0.3
output: none
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: Also, why do all the version numbers end in a space character?

Comment: typo.. there is no space character

Comment: i was able to extact the given number but i do  not know the logic on extratcing  next entry.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific and demonstrate an attempt at solving the problem. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the versions in a list and sort the list and Now you can simply get the next version from a list.

```
import json

with open('test.json') as fp:
    data = json.loads(fp.read())
res = sorted([x['version'] for x in data['release']])

def next_version(version):
    return res[res.index(version) + 1] if version in res and res.index(version) != len(res) -1 else None

print(next_version('10.0.1'))
```